# What is the difference between calling an exe with args in python and batch?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, arguments, exe

I'm trying to call an exe with multiple arguments and it works in command prompt or a batch code but not in python.

Batch/cmd code

```
"FooBar.exe" -script "some file path"
```

Python code tried

```python
from subprocess import call
args = ['FooBar.exe','-script','"some file path"']
call(args)

args = ['FooBar.exe -script "some file path"']
call(args)

args = ['FooBar.exe', '-script "some file path"']
call(args)
```

The batch code works fine but the arguments aren't getting passed to the software correctly (it doesn't use the arguments) when I use the python code.

Is there a fundamental difference in the way the arguments are passed between the two mathods?

In case its relevant I'm using:

- Python 3.6.1 from [Python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/)
- [PyCharm Community](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) Version: 2017.1.3
- Its commercial software I'm calling, not my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html:

> [`shlex.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) can be useful when determining the correct tokenization for args, especially in complex case.
>
> ```
> import shlex, subprocess
> command_line = input()
> /bin/vikings -input eggs.txt -output "spam spam.txt" -cmd "echo '$MONEY'"
> args = shlex.split(command_line)
> print(args)
> ['/bin/vikings', '-input', 'eggs.txt', '-output', 'spam spam.txt', '-cmd', "echo '$MONEY'"]
> p = subprocess.Popen(args) # Success!
> ```
>
> Note in particular that options (such as -input) and arguments (such as eggs.txt) that are separated by whitespace in the shell go in separate list elements, while arguments that need quoting or backslash escaping when used in the shell (such as filenames containing spaces or the echo command shown above) are single list elements.

It should be:

```
args = ['FooBar.exe', '-script', 'some file path']
```

Comment: Argh! Quotes not required around the path then, tried every combination but that one, working now, cheers.